# Is there a way to log all access to the phone include a photo

Tags: security

Is there a way to setup an android phone so that it logs all access and takes a photo each time it's accessed?

Comment: By access, do you mean "attempts to unlock the screen"? If yes, there are already apps for your use case. E.g. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=anti%20theft%20catcher&c=apps&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Not just attempts each time it's unlocked. The phone may be accessed with a correct password by multiple people